# Zonotope: Image of the Diagonals of a Hypercube Under a Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry, polytopes, discrete-geometry, frame-theory

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a matrix where $m \leq n$, and let $H = [-1,1]^n$ be the unit hypercube. One can form the zonotope $\mathcal{Z}(A) = \{Ax : x \in H\} \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, which is the image of $H$ under $A$. I am looking for a sufficient condition on $A$ that achieves the following:

> There are no opposing pairs of vertices in $H$ such that their image
> in $\mathcal{Z}(A)$ lie on a line in $\mathbb{R}^m$ which passes
> through two other points in $\mathcal{Z}(A)$ that are also the image
> of a different opposing pair of vertices in $H$.

Ignore any opposing pair of vertices in $H$ which map to $0$ in $\mathcal{Z}(A)$. Basically, I am looking for a condition on $A$ so that the image of the diagonals of the hypercube in $\mathcal{Z}(A)$ "don't collide".

**Example:**

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 4 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$, so that $m = 2$, $n = 3$. The images of the opposing pairs of vertices of $H$ are:

$$\pm(1,1,1) \mapsto \pm (5,7)$$
$$\pm(1,-1,1) \mapsto \pm (1,-1)$$
$$\pm(-1,1,1) \mapsto \pm (1,5)$$
$$\pm(-1,-1,1) \mapsto \pm (-3,-3)$$

One checks that the four lines each passing through these pairs of image points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are all distinct.

**Example:**

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$. The images of the opposing pairs of vertices of $H$ are:

$$\pm(1,1,1) \mapsto \pm (2,2)$$
$$\pm(1,-1,1) \mapsto (0,0)$$
$$\pm(-1,1,1) \mapsto \pm (0,2)$$
$$\pm(-1,-1,1) \mapsto \pm (-2,0)$$

We see that one opposing pair of vertices of $H$ was mapped to $0$. But ignoring this pair, the three lines each passing through the remaining pairs of image points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are all distinct, so $A$ still satisfies the condition.

**Non-Example:**

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$. The images of the opposing pairs of vertices of $H$ are:

$$\pm(1,1,1) \mapsto \pm (2,3)$$
$$\pm(1,-1,1) \mapsto \pm (0,-1)$$
$$\pm(-1,1,1) \mapsto \pm (0,3)$$
$$\pm(-1,-1,1) \mapsto \pm (-2,-1)$$

We see that the line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ passing through $\pm (0,-1)$ is the same line passing through $\pm (0,3)$, so two diagonals of $H$ have "collided" and $A$ is a "degenerate" matrix.

If it helps, I am studying the case when $A$ is a matrix whose columns are vectors from an equiangular tight frame, and the result I want to prove is that there is only one way (up to sign) such that a signed sum of all but one of the vectors in the frames yields a scalar multiple of the remaining vector.

Comment: In the last example, note that if you map $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R^3$ by sending $(1,0)$ to $(1,-1,1)$ and $(0,1)$ to $(-1,1,1)$, then the composition of this map with $A$ (whose matrix is easy to compute, I just didn't do it) has rank $1$ rather than $2$. I suspect that this is an easy way in general to examine each pair of diagonals in turn to look for such collisions. (Of course one has to first exclude any vertices that map to $0$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote the vertices of $H$ by $\partial^2 H$. Then what you want is that for all $x \in \partial^2 H$ there is no $y \in \partial^2 H$, such that $Ax$ and $Ay$ lie on the same line through the origin - so they should be linearly independent. We get these lines through the origin because the opposing vertices for each $x \in \partial^2 H$ is $-x$ and $A(-x) = -Ax$.

Note that the unit-cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has $2^n$ vertices, by identifying the opposing ones we cut this down to $2^{n-1}$ equivalence classes of antipodal vertices whose images under $A$ have to be pairwise linearly independent **or** get mapped to $0$ and thus land in the kernel of $A$.

By the above established equivalence relation we can identify each class with an element $(1,x_2,...,x_n) \in \partial^2 H$ (so the antipodal identification eliminates one choice in our string of $1$s and $-1$s). So a basic requirement is that for all $x'=(x_2,...,x_n)^T, y'=(y_2,...,y_n), x_j,y_j \in \{-1,1\}, x:= (1, x'^T)^T, y:= (1, y'^T)^T$ we have
$$
aAx + bAy = 0 \iff (a=b=0 \quad \text{or} \quad x \in \ker{A}).
$$

By considering some special cases you can get direct requirements for $A$; if you want some vertex to take "the kernel case" the requirement for $A$ is $Ax=0$, and if you want it to be linearly independent with the others you can get requirements from that. For example let $x$ be defined as above and let $y' = -x'$. Decompose $A$ as follows:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{1\cdot}' \\\ a_{\cdot1}' & A' \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $a_{11} \in \mathbb{R}, a_{1\cdot}' \in \mathbb{R}^{1,n-1}$ etc. Then
$$
Ax + Ay = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{1\cdot}' \\\ a_{\cdot1}' & A' \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\\ x'\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{1\cdot}' \\\ a_{\cdot1}' & A' \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\\ -x'\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} \\\ a_{\cdot 1}' \end{pmatrix}
$$
for example should not equal 0. So for this case we have either $Ax = 0$ or $a_{\cdot 1} \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}^{m,1}$. You can of course do the same for the other columns.

Are these the kind of conditions you had in mind?